# Translate String(Text) to Different Lagunage at Runtime in android

Tags: java, android, translation

I have a string obtained from `EditText`.

```
String test= et.getText.toString();
test=" My name is john tokest";
```

After that I have spinner with different language like, **English, Chinese, French, Hindi**.

If I choose **French**, I want to display in text view in **French** translate test string.

like this: **Mon nom est john tokest**

Is it possible in android? or not?

Note: I have done this successfully if I have created **value-fr** folder in res and included respective string, but I want to do this at run time.

Comment: Why not use google translate? https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: Localization is the keyword http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html - did not see a dynamic example though - at first glance

Answer (score 1):

Add [google translation jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/downloads/detail?name=google-api-translate-java-0.95.jar&can=2&q=) in your project. And then you can use it like this:

```
String test="My name is john tokest";
try {
        String translatedText = Translate.execute(test, Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);//You can pass params as per text input and desired output.
        System.out.println(translatedText)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[Reference article](http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-translate-text-from-one-language.html)

Comment: Had to a add this line:
Translate.setHttpReferrer("www.leboncoin.fr");
www.example.com does not work.
And now I get Error retrieving translation.

Comment: @Yster did you ever figure this out.